# Find and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to do a find and replace in Notepad++
I have a file that has an open bracket a number and a comma
I want to replace the number leaving the value null
Ex: Find: "(32," Repalce with: "('',"
The numbers range from two to four digits. I have done it before in BBEdit, but do not have access to it on this computer. can I do this in Notepad++?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the number replace with 2 single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the following regex for the search term:

```
\((\d{2,4}),
```

And select "regular expression" option.

Comment: I tried this first but I couldn't get notepad++ to work with a range modifier. Which version of notepad++ is this? I may have an outdated version.

Comment: Notepad++ recently added regex range modifiers. I'm not sure of the exact version, but my current version of 6.15 is working with it.

Comment: Yes, my version was 5.8.2 so this solution may be very version dependent. I should probably update it.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get it to work. This assumes that something other than a digit will follow the replaced number (like a comma or a space).

Find what:

```
\(\d+
```

Replace with:

```
(''
```

Comment: His question indicated that he needs the range of numbers to be between 2 and 4, which this solution does not account for.

Comment: Actually, he said that the numbers range from 2 to 4 but not that there may be values out of that range that shouldn't match. If all the numbers are between 2-4 and he wants to do this to all of them, then this still meets that need.

Comment: @MattRamey If that's truly a need, then yours is better. I'm only offering this as this is an easier solution to remember.